# How can I set the value of an Address field on one entity with the value of an Address field from another entity?

Tags: 8

I am trying to figure out how to programmatically set an Address field on an entity (Profile) with the value of a different Address field from a different entity (User).

This should be trivial and I have tried this:

```
function example_user_insert($user) {
  $profile = Profile::create([
    'type' => 'customer',
    'uid' => $user->id(),
    'is_default' => true,
  ]);

  $profile->set('address', $user->field_billing_address);
  $profile->save();
}
```

Although the profile entity gets saved; the Address field is not filled in and there are no errors generated. I have successfully set pieces of an Address field with its pieces (country, city, etc); but hoping I don't need to do this as it seems like I should be able to just do it as I show above. I have done a similar technique for entity ref fields where I simply do something like:

$node->set('term1', $node2->term2); and it works as expected.

Comment: Maybe `$profile->set('address', $user->field_billing_address->getValue());`?

Comment: @Clive - AWESOME!! yes, that works. Thank you so much!.